# Serverless framework lambda function access denied to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting "Access Denied" when trying to put object into S3 inside a lambda function? I have the serverless AWS user with **AdministorAccess** and allow access to s3 resource inside `serverless.yml`:

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
```

Edit - here are the files

**serverless.yml**

```
service: testtest
app: testtest
org: workx

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/create
          method: get
```

**handler.js**

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// get reference to S3 client
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

// Uload the content to s3 and allow download
async function uploadToS3(content) {
  console.log('going to upload to s3!');

  const Bucket = 'mtest-exports';
    const key = 'testtest.csv';

  try {
    const destparams = {
        Bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: content,
        ContentType: "text/csv",
    };

    console.log('going to put object', destparams);
    const putResult = await S3.putObject(destparams).promise(); 

    return putResult;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  } 
}

module.exports.hello = async event => {
  const result = await uploadToS3('hello world');

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(result),
  };
};
```

Comment: Try `"Resource": "*"`? If that doesn't help, please edit your question to include the code that is causing the error.

Comment: try this `Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan also tried your method and it didn't work

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is causing the error.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein both files are included, thanks for looking at it

Answer (score 0):

I was using TypeScript plugin - @serverless/typescript. I used it to create Lambda function that will resize images that are uploaded to S3 + do some kind of content moderation.

Here is the content of **serverless.ts** file:

```
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';
import resizeImageLambda from '@functions/resizeImageLambda';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
    service: 'myservice-image-resize',
    frameworkVersion: '3',
    plugins: ['serverless-esbuild'],
    provider: {
        name: 'aws',
        stage: 'dev',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        profile: 'myProjectProfile', // reference to your local AWS profile created by serverless config command
        // architecture: 'arm64', // to support Lambda w/ graviton    
        iam: {
            role: {
                statements: [
                    {
                        Effect: 'Allow',
                        Action: [
                            's3:GetObject',
                            's3:PutObject',
                            's3:PutObjectAcl',
                            's3:ListBucket',
                            'rekognition:DetectModerationLabels'
                        ],
                        Resource: [
                            'arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*',
                            'arn:aws:s3:::myBucket',
                            'arn:aws:s3:::/*',
                            '*'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        Effect: 'Allow',
                        Action: [
                            's3:ListBucket',
                            'rekognition:DetectModerationLabels'
                        ],
                        Resource: ['arn:aws:s3:::myBucket']
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        // architecture: 'arm64',
        runtime: 'nodejs16.x',
        environment: {
            AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
            NODE_OPTIONS: '--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000',
            SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME:
                '${self:custom.myEnvironment.SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME.${self:custom.myStage}}',
            DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME:
                '${self:custom.myEnvironment.DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME.${self:custom.myStage}}'
        }
    },
    // import the function via paths
    functions: { resizeImageLambda },    
    package: { individually: true },
    custom: {
        esbuild: {
            bundle: true,
            minify: false,
            sourcemap: true,
            exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
            target: 'node16',
            define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
            platform: 'node',
            concurrency: 10,
            external: ['sharp'],
            packagerOptions: {
                scripts:
                    'rm -rf node_modules/sharp && SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=glibc sharp'
            }
        },
        myEnvironment: {
            SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME: {
                dev: 'myBucket',
                prod: 'myBucket-prod'
            },
            DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME: {
                dev: 'myBucket',
                prod: 'myBucketProd'
            }
        },
        myStage: '${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}'
    }
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

**resizeImageLambda.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable no-template-curly-in-string */
// import { Config } from './config';

export const handlerPath = (context: string) =>
    `${context.split(process.cwd())[1].substring(1).replace(/\\/g, '/')}`;

export default {
    handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
    events: [
        {
            s3: {
                bucket: '${self:custom.myEnvironment.SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME.${self:custom.myStage}}',
                event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*',
                existing: true,
                forceDeploy: true // for existing buckets
            }
        }
    ],
    timeout: 15 * 60, // 15 min
    memorySize: 2048
};
```

I remember there were few issues when I wanted to connect it to existing buckets (created outside serverless framework) such as IAM policy was **not re-created / updated properly** (see **forceDeploy** end **existing** parameters in function.events[0].s3 properties in resizeLambda.ts file)